# Primefaces draggable event only

Tags: jsf, primefaces, draggable

I want to make a list of primefaces panels draggable and i want to catch the event in order to save the position.
Is that possible?
Thank you, i am here for further explanation

The jquery method that i have used:

```
$(function() {
 $(" .dragPanel").draggable({
  start: function() { },
  drag: function() {
      var theId= $( this).attr("id");
      $("#form0\\:thePanelId").val(theId);
      var offset = $( this ).offset();
      var left = offset.left;
      var top = offset.top;

      var parent = $(window);

      var leftParent = parent.width();
      var topParent = parent.height();

      $("#form0\\:left").val(100*left/leftParent);
      $("#form0\\:top").val(100*top/topParent);
      $("#form0\\:leftParent").val(leftParent);
      $("#form0\\:topParent").val(topParent);
  },

  stop: function() {
    jQuery( "[id$='buttonId']" ).click();
 } });
  })
```

**form snippet :**

```
   <p:inputText id="left" value="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.left}" style="display: none;"> </p:inputText>
   <p:inputText id="top" value="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.top}" style="display: none;"> </p:inputText>
   <p:inputText id="leftParent" value="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.leftParent}" style="display: none;"> </p:inputText>
   <p:inputText id="topParent" value="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.topParent}" style="display: none;"> </p:inputText>
   <p:inputText id="thePanelId" value="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.thePanelId}" style="display: none;"></p:inputText>

   <h:commandButton id="buttonId" actionListener="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.saveDragChange()}" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: What is exactly that you wanna catch, the x ,y position in the window?

Comment: yes i want to catch the x and y positions

Comment: If you want to catch the x, y position I don think the jsf components support this, and you wont be able to do it in the server side with java. You could do it in the client side with js.

Comment: I have used a jquery method that i add to my question below, but the problem is that when the button is cliked the page is refreshed at each move, and this is not a friendly use. Is there a way to send my data from jquery to server with as ajax request? Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the button upload the form with ajax change by

```
<h:commandButton id="buttonId" style="display: none;" 
 actionListener="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.saveDragChange()}"  >
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":rootViewId" />
</h:commadButton>
```

This `execute="@form"` will upload the entire form, `render=":rootViewId" will search for the id from the root view of the document and will upload any changes made to bean.

other way to do it and I like more since you're using **primefaces**. Is to use the pf commandButton that is ajax based for default

```
<p:commandButton id="buttonId" style="display: none;" 
 actionListener="#{reportDetailsManagedBean.saveDragChange()}" update="@form" />
```

the attribute in the `<p:commandButton` `update` will update the form after the ajax is completed

I hope this help you , greets

---

> **Edited**

About just working for the first drag...

In this line Im not sure is this works:

but you better use typical jquery sintax

replace:

```
jQuery( "[id$='buttonId']" ).click();
```

by

```
$("#buttonId").click();
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Actually both worked but only for the first component.(I mean i can move one panel but then i can't move none of the rest of the panels). Strange ... Is there s.th that i am missing?

Comment: What about the js console? Is there any errors? or everything is just fine?, because Im not sure if this might work `jQuery( "[id$='buttonId']" ).click();`

Comment: No there is nor error in the js console, and for the button it's clicked and action is invoked.